# How to create a new group in Azure AD using Go SDK?

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory

I need to create a group in Azure Active Directory programmatically using Go SDK, I somehow struggle to find the learning resources to do that. Can I get an example or explanation how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement, you can make use of **[Microsoft Graph SDK for Go](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go#microsoft-graph-sdk-for-go)** by integrating the *Microsoft Graph API* into your *Go application*.

Make sure to ***install and import*** required libraries and create `authProvider` instance.

You can refer this **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=go#example-1-create-a-microsoft-365-group)** to create group in Azure AD via Graph API that includes code snippets for **`Go`** too.

Make sure to **consent required permissions** before running the query. Based on the request body you specify; **`group type`** will be decided accordingly.

**To create Security group, I gave request body like below:**

[image]

You can get **GO code** by selecting [**code snippets**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJSK6.png):

```
//THE GO SDK IS IN PREVIEW. NON-PRODUCTION USE ONLY
graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)

requestBody := msgraphsdk.NewGroup()
description := "Example of Security Group"
requestBody.SetDescription(&description)
displayName := "Sri Security"
requestBody.SetDisplayName(&displayName)
requestBody.SetGroupTypes( []string {
}
mailEnabled := false
requestBody.SetMailEnabled(&mailEnabled)
mailNickname := "test"
requestBody.SetMailNickname(&mailNickname)
securityEnabled := true
requestBody.SetSecurityEnabled(&securityEnabled)
result, err := graphClient.Groups().Post(requestBody)
```

After running the above query,  **Security Group** created successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "THE GO SDK IS IN PREVIEW. NON-PRODUCTION USE ONLY". Why can't I use it on production?

Comment: This means it's not completely available for production and sometimes, you may not get expected results. ***Some changes are yet to be done*** as it is currently in Community Preview. So, it is suggested to use for non-Production use only for now. Please check this **[note](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go#section-readme)**